# How to prove the following properties about $\chi_1^2$?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared-test

Given two independent r.v. $X\sim N(\mu_1, 1)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_2, 1)$. What is
$$
f(x)=P(\min\{X^2, Y^2\}>c).
$$

Comment: The second equation is an equality:$$P(Y^2>\chi_1^2(\alpha))=\alpha$$(irrespective of $X$). The first inequality follows immediately by considering the value of $\min\{X^2,Y^2\}$ relative to the value of $Y^2$.

Comment: Is it $Y\sim N(\mu_1, 1)$ or $Y\sim N(\mu_2, 1)$ ? If that is not a typo on your part, where does $\mu_2$ come from?

Comment: Hint: when $X^2 \gt Y^2,$ what is a simple expression for $\min(X^2,Y^2)$?

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $Y^2$ given $\mu_2 = 0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to show that under $\mu_1\mu_2=0$,
> $$
> P(\min\{X^2, Y^2\}>\chi_1^2(\alpha))\le \alpha
> $$
> where $\chi_1^2(\alpha)$ is the $1-\alpha$ quantile of chi-square.

If $\mu_1 \mu_2 = 0$ then either $\mu_1= 0, \mu_2 = 0$, $\mu_1= 0, \mu_2 \neq 0$, or $\mu_1 \neq 0, \mu_2 = 0$.

Consider one case:

If $\mu_1= 0, \mu_2 \neq 0$ then $X^2$ is $\chi_1^2$ distributed and you have $$P(X^2>\chi_1^2(\alpha))= \alpha$$ For any other variable $Y$ you have $$P(\min\{X^2, Y^2\}>\chi_1^2(\alpha))\leq P(X^2> \chi_1^2(\alpha)) = \alpha$$ The probability is not higher because if $\min\{X^2, Y^2\}$ is higher than some point than so is $X^2$, and the condition $X^2> \chi_1^2(\alpha)$ must at least include all the cases with the condition $\min\{X^2, Y^2\} > \chi_1^2(\alpha)$.

For the other cases you can reason in the same way.

Comment: @quas I do not follow the last alinea from your last edit.

Comment: Regarding the question $$f(x)=P(\min\{X^2, Y^2\}>\chi_1^2(0.05))$$ Note that you can consider the $X,Y$ as bivariate normal distributed. You can draw in a plot of $X,Y$ the regions where $\min\{X^2, Y^2\}>c$, which will relate to combinations of $X>\sqrt{c}$, $X<-\sqrt{c}$, $Y>\sqrt{c}$, $Y<-\sqrt{c}$. The end result is that you only need to express the probability that $X,Y$ lies within a few rectanglar regions. This is not too difficult to express.

Comment: $$P(\min(X^2,Y^2) > c^2) = P( |X| >c \text{ and } |Y| > c) = P( |X| >c ) \cdot P(|Y| > c)$$ From this expression you can also see why $P(\min\{X^2, Y^2\}>\chi_1^2(\alpha))\le \alpha$